# How to pull an image URL from a database and populate a Meta tag

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I am trying to figure out how to pull an image URL from a database and insert it into a `<meta>` tag.

Say `picture` is the name of database column that contains the relative URL of an image. The meta code I have is:

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.iowalum.com/images/mainimage.jpg">
```

How can replace `/images/mainimage.jpg` with the value of `picture`?

Comment: Does the database store the actual image (binary) or the url to the image? You will need the URL or physical path to determine the URL.

Comment: it stores it as the image path so it would store it as like /images/mainimage.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your query is correctly pulling the information then you just need to reference the value within `<cfoutput>` tags to build your Meta tag.

Something like:

```
<cfquery name="qryName" ...>
    <!--- your query here --->
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="qryName">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.iowalum.com#qryName.columnName#">
</cfoutput>
```

The `#qryName.columnName#` variable should be the column name from your database that holds the image URL.